# mysql insert on duplicate key update know whether it took place

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, insert-update, on-duplicate-key

In an application I'm building I use a lot of insert on duplicate key updates. My issue is that in my application I kind of need to know whether or not it was an insert or an update so my code can make the appropriate decisions. Does anyone know how I can test for this?

I'm using perl's DBI module if anyone knows a way specific to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.

So, you should be able to check the return-value of the `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY` queries; if it's 1, the row was inserted, if it is 2, it was updated.

Comment: It always returns 1, even if it does an update, on Perl 10.1, DBI 1.616 with mysql 5.0.